# ¿Cómo crear correctamente una lista de reproduccion de audio (Playlist) en Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mediaplayer

Estoy haciendo un reproductor de audio y quiero poder crear listas de reproducción (**Playlist**), tengo una función que crea una nueva lista a partir de un nombre dado, la lista se crea sin ningun problema, pero a la hora de agregar una nueva canción, es como si la lista estubiera rota, simplemente no se agrega, e probado con otros reproductores de audio y algunos incluso arrojan errores a la hora de agregar alguna canción  a las listas que e creado usando esa función, a mi particularmente me da error, se perfectamente que la api de playlist está deprecada, pero no encuentro una mejor forma de crear una nueva playlist.

Función para crear la playlist:

```
    private fun crearNuevaLista(pname: String): Uri? {
        val playlists: Uri = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
        val c: Cursor = context.contentResolver.query(playlists, null, null, null, null) ?: return null
        var playlistId: Long = 0
        c.moveToFirst()
        do {
            try{
                val plname: String = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.NAME))
                if (plname.equals(pname, ignoreCase = true)) {
                    playlistId = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists._ID))
                    break
                }
            } catch (e: CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException) {  }

        } while (c.moveToNext())
        c.close()
        if (playlistId != 0L) {
            val deleteUri: Uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(playlists, playlistId)
            // delete the playlist if exists
            context.contentResolver.delete(deleteUri, null, null)
        }
        // Creating playlist pname
        val v1 = ContentValues()

        v1.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.NAME, pname)
        v1.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis())
        v1.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.DATE_MODIFIED, System.currentTimeMillis())
        val uri = context.contentResolver.insert(playlists, v1)
        context.contentResolver.notifyChange(Uri.parse("content://media"), null);
        return uri
        // Added playList
    }
```

Función para añadir una canción a la playlist:

```
    private fun addToPlaylist(ids: LongArray?, playlistid: Long, context: Context) {
        if (ids != null) {
            val size = ids.size
            val values = arrayOfNulls<ContentValues>(size)
            val resolver = context.contentResolver
            val uri = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.getContentUri("external", playlistid)
            val cur = resolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null)
            cur!!.moveToFirst()
            try {
                val base = cur.getInt(0) // <- this fires CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException 
                for (i in 0 until size) {
                    values[i] = ContentValues()
                    values[i]!!.put(
                        MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.PLAY_ORDER,
                        Integer.valueOf(base + i)
                    )
                    values[i]!!.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.AUDIO_ID, ids[i])
                }
                resolver.bulkInsert(uri, values)
            } catch (e: CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException){
                Toast.makeText(context, "A ocurrido un error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } finally {
                cur.close()
            }
        }
    }
```

El error solo ocurre cuando agrego una canción a las listas de reproducción que creo usando la función **crearNuevaLista**, con las creadas por otras apps de audio las canciones se agregar perfectamente, creo que me está faltando un paso importante.

Comment: Hola, siempre es importante especificar el error, agregar el error mostrado en el LogCat., saludos.

Comment: hola, la verdad es que no me muestra ningún error, el problema es que crea la playlist(sin errores), pero ningún reproductor de audio puede agregar canciones a dichas listas.

Comment: En los "catch" agrega que imprima el error en el LogCat, de lo contrario el problema pueden ser varias causas. Imprime el error de esta forma: catch (e: CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException) { Log.e("ERROR", "crearNuevaLista() ${e.getMessage}) } , lo mismo en el mètodo addToPlayList : } catch (e: CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException){
                Toast.makeText(context, "A ocurrido un error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()    Log.e("ERROR", "addToPlayList() ${e.getMessage}) 
            }